# contents not copied when pushing to std::queue

Tags: c++, queue

I'm using a queue to push a message buffer for processing later on, but the contents aren't being copied correctly to the queue.

My code is -

```
void QueuePacket(MessageBuffer &&buffer)
{
    _writeQueue.push(std::move(buffer));
}
```

_writeQueue is nothing but an std::queue of MessageBuffer.

MessageBuffer contains a `std::vector<uint8_t>` named storage.

`buffer` **before** the push - 
[image]

The write queue **before** the push -
[image]

the Write queue **after** the push -
[image]

I'm using C++14. 
Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: https://github.com/TrinityCore/TrinityCore/blob/3.3.5/src/common/Utilities/MessageBuffer.h ? - Are you trying to copy it ?

Comment: @Blacktempel yes. I'm practicing some multithreaded networking.

Comment: Show the code for your MessageBuffer class.

Comment: Provide a [mcve]

Comment: @SagunKho Trying to separate this from TrinityCore can be hard enough, you should show the full call stack until you get to `QueuePacket`. There can be multiple issues, with that code I can only say, that the original code on github works fine.

Comment: @SagunKho Also check all your pre-conditions leading to `QueuePacket`. In the original code there are quite a lot conditions in order to call into the function. https://github.com/TrinityCore/TrinityCore/blob/3.3.5/src/server/game/Server/WorldSocket.cpp